# grub error when booting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, bootloader

I have 2 hard drives on my server and I have previously installed CentOS on one of the hard drives. I'm not sure which, but I am guessing it's the second.

I fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the first one I will say, but after the successful installation (which I assume it has repartitioned my hard drives) when it reboots I get this error:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
```

[image]

I tried to use rescue mode to fix what the issue is and am brought to a screen that asks to choose the boot device I want, and when I choose `/dev/sda1` it says I can't use it.

[image]

[image]

How do I fix this and/or how can I wipe out everything on my 2 hard drives first, before starting another fresh install?

Comment: You show sda as gpt partitioned. If installing in BIOS mode you must have a 1 or2 MB unformatted partition for grub to install correctly. Or if UEFI you must have the 100 to 500MB efi system partition (ESP). Which is FAT32 formatted with boot flag. I normally add both to every gpt drive, and all my drives now are gpt.  Is system UEFI? http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I dont mind to wipe the 2 disk clean..look at my #2 question..so i i just want to do fresh install and i actually want to wipe data from both drives clean...how do i do that? i think it is using gpt partition.,..also where do i set what mode to install? also i think there is conflict or this problem because there is data on the drives, i installed centos on one of the drives before so i am guessing that is what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just used gparted from http://gparted.org/
and deleted all the partitions

there was the second drive that was locked because it uses lvm2
So i used `lvscan` to check all the volumes on it and then used `lvremove` to remove all the volumes, then i was able to delete it as well, before using `lvremove` the partition was locked and i could not delete

So have 2 fresh hard drives back again